# Is there anyway to disable the styling of select elements in the JQuerymobile libraries

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

I'd like to have a native select-menu within my application, so it would be great if I could just set a flag like 'data-theming="none"' to mark this control as not to be styled by jquery mobile. is this possible?

I've had a look at http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0a2/jquery.mobile-1.0a2.js and can see that it applies the selectmenu() function to all select elements bar ui-slider ones.

I'm pretty new to JQuery, my question is, is it possible to override the selectmenu() function in the JQuery mobile library with my own one that does nothing and if so how do I do this? My other option is to move away from the CDN hosted JQueryMobile and download and edit the existing one.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`data-role="nojs"` should do the trick.

This attribute makes jquery mobile skip the element and its contents.

As a workaround I suggest:

wrap the select in a div you can locate easily and add something like this to the page:

```
$(function(){
$d=$('#thedivthere');
$s=$d.find('select').attr('class','').clone();
$d.empty().append($s);
});
```

This will not be covered by jquery mobile, because adding this happens later. And it removes any classes that jqm added.

Comment: I've just tried this and it doesn't work. I put the datarole on the select element which had no effect. Then I put it on a div around a select which just hid everything (left -9999px; position: absolute).

Comment: I will test it later, I didn't have an opportunity to use this data role and I might be mistaken on what it's for. Added a workaround.

Comment: Hello, just to confirm that the above worked a treat for me. Still wondering if there is a solution to override the selectmenu() function and if so how do I go about doing that?

Comment: you can replace the widget, but it has to be done in the right moment. selectmenu is provided by a widget that is a part of jquery mobile. It might be possible to disable it in the future. Now you can redefine the widget to do nothing.

Answer (score 3):

```
data-role="none"
```

http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0b1/#/demos/1.0b1/docs/forms/forms-all-native.html